# Only certain xmldoc tags are relevant for IntelliSense

Tags: c#, comments, intellisense, xml-documentation

Microsoft has [all sorts of documented xml tags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/recommended-tags-for-documentation-comments) for doc comments (beginning with a triple-slash), but some of them (e.g. `<list>`) don't actually change the formatting of the tooltip text IntelliSense gives me, and instead it just gets thrown in a jumbled heap:
[image]

These are the doc comments that produced that tooltip:

```
/// <summary>
/// <code>None of this gets formatted</code>
/// Test list:
/// <list type="number"><listheader><term>testT</term><description>testD</description></listheader>
/// <item><term>This gets</term><description>crammed</description></item></list> 
/// See <see cref="unixEpoch"/>
/// </summary>
/// <param name="date"></param>
/// <param name="TimeZoneOption"></param>
/// <returns>Things that have <code>code</code></returns>
```

So my questions are:

1. It seems to be that anything that isn't starred [in the MS doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/recommended-tags-for-documentation-comments) is just ignored for IntelliSense purposes, but why even have a `<code>` tag if the text inside isn't going to look any different?
2. Why does the `<returns>` part not show up in the tooltip at all?
3. Is there any way to force a newline that I'm missing?

Comment: Yay, got Tumbleweed badge! Now can I have help (at least with #3)?

Comment: Most of the tags are only used, when generating an html documentation or windows help format file format. i.e. all docs in MSDN and learn.microsoft.com are generated from these XML Doc definitions, i.e. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string(v=vs.110).aspx